# SQL Query solution?

Tags: sql

If I had to find data from a group of tables such as the length of all the films combined featuring the first name "Roderigo", is this how I would do it?

```
SELECT SUM(m.length) AS "Films with Roderigo"
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_actor x
ON (m.MOVIE_ID = x.MOVIE_ID)
INNER JOIN actor a
ON (x.ACTOR_ID = a.ACTOR_ID)
WHERE a.actor_lname = 'Roderigo';
```

Comment: Yes, that should do the job. Just noticed that you have put `actor_lname` in the query whereas the question says `first name`.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not how you do it in general. It might work in some cases. But if you have two actors with first name Roderigo that play in the same movie you count the movie twice.

```
SELECT SUM(m.length) AS total_length
FROM movie m
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM movie_actor x INNER JOIN
    actor a ON x.ACTOR_ID = a.ACTOR_ID
  WHERE a.actor_fname = 'Roderigo' AND m.MOVIE_ID = x.MOVIE_ID
)
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(m.length) AS total_length
FROM movie m
WHERE m.MOVIE_ID IN (
  SELECT x.MOVIE_ID
  FROM movie_actor x INNER JOIN
    actor a ON x.ACTOR_ID = a.ACTOR_ID
  WHERE a.actor_fname = 'Roderigo'
)
```

Comment: would this be a suitable answer for finding the genre's of films Carey Mulligan has been in?                                                                  `SELECT DISTINCT f.genre AS "Carey Mulligan genres"
FROM movie m
WHERE m.movie_ID IN (
 SELECT x.movie_ID
 FROM movie_actor x
 INNER JOIN actor a
 ON x.actor_ID = a.actor_ID
 AND a.actor_lname = 'Mulligan');'`

Comment: @randdotname yes, except that you forgot `a.actor_fname = 'Carey'` and you probably mean `m.genre`?

Comment: yeah I fixed that after I posted the comment, thanks for the example.